# How to get out of loop with no break if possible

Tags: loops

How do I get out of the for loop without using break? I am trying to go through the dir and check if true or false. If false then leave the loop.

```
fun testLetter(parameters here): Boolean {

    for (i in j) when (dir) {
        "dir" -> {
            if (board[row][col] != i|| board[row][col] != k) {
                willFit = false
            } else {
               ... continueOn
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to break out of the `while` loop when you've found that `willFit = false`.  It's not breaking out because the code is still looping through your `for` loop.  So, if you set `willFit = false` and then `break` out of the `for` loop, it will end the `for` loop, then check your condition of the `while` loop and find that `willFit` is now `false`, thus breaking out of the `while` loop too.

For example, each time you set `willFit = false`, do the following:

```
willFit = false
break
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to stay away from using a break.

Comment: Why not use ``break``? That's what it's for! Otherwise you'll have to replace your ``for`` loop with another ``while`` that checks your condition and manually iterates over the words, it's a lot more work. ``for`` loops do a fixed number of iterations, and ``break`` is how you exit them early